Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about TumbleBit‽
TumbleBit is a second layer protocol that allows payment hubs to offer trustless anonymous payments to their users.
Currently, we have three questions about TumbleBit, let's ask and learn! 
Please use tumblebit to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about the anonymity promises, trustlessness, the Scaling Bitcoin presentation of Ethan and Leen, the TumbleBit paper, TumbleBits compatibility, implementation, or whatever else you want to know about it.
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-12-01. Happy posting!

This week, one question was asked about Tumblebit with a total of one answer:

Would it be visible that someone moved bitcoins to or from tumblebit? – urza.cc [+1]

Thanks for posting!
